# how to write a parameter mapping equation

Tags: math

I am wondering what is the mathematically correct way of writing a mapping equation. I have a slider range (0, 100) that maps to another range of value (v_min, v_max). Is there any standard way of writing rather than:

v = slider_value * (v_max - v_min) / (100 - 0)

The question is about whether there is a standard mathematical way to write mapping (a, b) to (c, d). It is for paper documentation rather than coding itself.

Thanks

Comment: if its not a coding question you are on the wrong site. Maybe try math.stackexchange.com, although maybe reviewing some journals in your field would be more productive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming and coding.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `v_min` to get correct result.

And more general formula for linear mapping is

```
v = v_min + (slider_value - slider_min) * (v_max - v_min) / (slider_max - slider_min)
```

Note that `Cf = (v_max - v_min) / (slider_max - slider_min)` is known constant for given mapping, so small optimization is possible to avoid excessive calculations at every step:

```
v = v_min + (slider_value - slider_min) * Cf
```

Comment: Hi, it is not about the mapping method I am asking, sorry if that is not clear. It is about documenting. How to writing the equation in a paper? Whether there is a standard way to documenting how to map (a, b) to (c, d).

Answer (score 1):

I think the function you're looking for is `Rescale`, because that does exactly what you ask:

```
v = Rescale[slider_value, {0, 100}, {v_min, v_max}]
```

Example:

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0},
    Column[{
        Dynamic[x],
        Dynamic[Rescale[x, {0, 100}, {-200, 300}]],
        Slider[Dynamic[x], {0, 100}]
    }]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Interpolation`

```
Interpolation[{{slidermin,vmin},{slidermax,vmax}}]@sliderval
```

(you may need `InterpolationOrder->1` to surpress a warning)

this is fundamentally just building the expression given in the other answer, but this will throw warnings if you go out of range.

Comment: Hi, it is not about the mapping method I am asking, sorry if that is not clear. It is about documenting. How to writing the equation in a paper? Whether there is a standard way to documenting how to map (a, b) to (c, d).

Comment: so why the mathematica tag?